# Can't get data from a single field in firebase RTDB using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am trying to read data from Firebase RTDB using flutter but can't seem to get the value from a specific child.

I have a drop linked to the `Car` field in my database which works fine and pulls the value:

[image: Database Structure]

After pressing a button, I am trying to run a query to get the `Brand` linked to the car select using the following:

```dart
void CreateNewDeal(String selectedcar) {
    try{
        print('check car inside function - $selectedcar');
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CarList2').orderByChild('Car').equalTo(selectedcar).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
            print('${snap.value['Brand']}');
        });

    }catch(e){
      print('error in reading the brand');
    }
}
```

I keep getting a null on the print statement.

If I, however, change the print statement to remove the `['Brand]' it retrieves the full tree for the specific node.

How do I only retrieve the 'Brand' for the corresponding 'Car'.

---

EDIT:
I tried to run the code with just `$snap.value` and this returns the whole tree for the specific child. when I then change the print to `print(snap.value[0]['Brand'])` it then prints the Brand if I were to select the Car linked to item 0 in the tree. If I change this to any other Car selected in my dropdown, it does not give me the Brand and returns a null. I though maybe it was related to the 0 index so I purposefully selected item 1 and changed the print to `snap.value[1]['Brand']` but this does not work either.

This cannot possibly be null because when I physically check the database, values are present. and i am unsure as to why it works for item 0 and not for nay other item

---

EDIT

The reason i was experiencing this issue is because of the way my tree was setup. i did further investigations and eventually had to change the indexes as seen above in my tree screenshot.

see my other question and answer below as to how to restructure the tree if need be.:

[Flutter - Firebase RTDB read issue for node at index 0, 1 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107352/flutter-firebase-rtdb-read-issue-for-node-at-index-0-1-and-2/62168815#62168815)

Comment: Try to print `snap.value[selectedcar]`

Comment: @SanjaySharma, That doesnt work and should, because 'selectedcar' is the `value` of the field, not the `name` of the field

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did you check the length of `snap` in debugging mode

Comment: @SanjaySharma, it definitely returns values. as indicated, if i print `snap.value` it returns all values in my tree. i can eve add it to a `List<dynamic>` and print the list. its an issue trying to extract the specific field 'Brand' or any other field which is causing a null which should not be the case as there is data in the field

Comment: @SanjaySharma, When printing `snapshot.value` there seems to be a null in the beginning of the print in the console. any idea what that is?`[null, { Brand: Alfa Romeo,  Car: Alfa Romeo Guilia 2.0T Standard Automatic Petrol Sedan RWD}]`

Comment: I am not sure, but it might be due to the data issues. Do you have any empty object inside `CarList`

Comment: @SanjaySharma, No empties, every single object is populated. i am 100% sure, because i have this same list being used for a Android app. i am buys transforming the app into Flutter. so this data should work

Comment: Try to remove once()

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to incorrectly setting up the database. you must use indexes. please see my other question which point to the way to do it

[Flutter - Firebase RTDB read issue for node at index 0, 1 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107352/flutter-firebase-rtdb-read-issue-for-node-at-index-0-1-and-2)